# Interpolation in a Mollier diagram

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I'm currently going a little more in depth with thermodynamics and I'm trying to familiarise myself with Mollier's diagram. What I don't understand is how to read precise values given the initial conditions. For example, I am given $p=0.6MPa, T=473,15K$ and I want precise values for enthalpy, entropy and specific volume.

Since there is no line for $p=0.6MPa$ (at least in my graph), all I can say is that it falls between the lines representing $0.5MPa$ and $1MPa$, which are there.
Similarly for T, I know it will fall somewhere between the 440K and the 480K isobars, so I do have a vague idea of what to expect for $h, s, v$, but how do I find out the exact values for all?

Thank you

Comment: If you are dealing with a limited range of independent variables, you could try a quadratic curve fit of known points on the diagram.  Then, any interpolation would be very close to the true values.  In addition, what kind of accuracy to you require, and if you are reading values off of a diagram, how accurately can you read them?

Comment: Most people would use linear interpolation.

Comment: Judging form the problems I'm working on, 5 significant figures is the precision I'm looking for. As for the interpolation I think linear is enough, but what should I consider? The lines at the edges? Or should I look for intersections?

Answer (score 0):

I will bet you one sugar-glazed doughnut (my standard wager) that you will find on-line a mollier chart calculator which spits out the values you want to three-place accuracy when you plug in the other variables. You will have to come to Corvallis, Oregon to claim your doughnut.

Comment: As much as I would enjoy the trip, whether it's to claim or to buy you a sugar-glazed doughnut, I'm afraid I still need to understand how to do the interpolation by myself. The exam I'm preparing for doesn't allow online calculators unfortunately...

Comment: Back in the day, I just did it by eye, and two-place accuracy was good enough fpr full credit on the thermo exam. Three places requires you to resolve 1/1000 of a graph unit, which I could not do. If you come here I'll buy you a doughnut regardless, on general principles.

Answer (score 0):

You really should be using steam tables and not the Mollier diagram. This link has a fairly comprehensive set of tables. Use linear interpolation for values in between.

https://www.ohio.edu/mechanical/thermo/property_tables/H2o/H2O_Super2.html

Also, as @niels nielsen pointed out, there are on line calculators. I found this one to be pretty good. https://mhi-inc.com/superheated_steam/steam-calculator-superheated-tables.html

Hope this helps